# How to break a string line with many values to a single field?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I don't speak English very well...

[image]

I have this case, for FID in field "CPFS*" exists some codes. I need in field "identifica" only one.
For exemple:
to [FID = 0 identifica = 00417549210],
to [FID = 1 identifica = 75434180291],
to [FID = 2 identifica = 03258000220]
...

I did by this code:

[image]

But this gave to me the field "identifica" in the exemple image... Does someone have other idea?

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, ["CPFS_CNPJS", "identifica"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
    lista = row[0].split(",")
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        row[1] = lista[i]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the focused Q&A format of this site.

Comment: In your list of examples, most, but not all, were given the first code in the list of values. (FID 1 was assigned the second code.) Are you OK with all using the first code?

Comment: Could you please describe what your desired output product looks like? Do you need the first item in the CPFS* field written to the identifica field?

Comment: For each CPF i have one feature, and because thuis, FID 0 and 1 are igual, but in field identifica I need just one code, one to FID 0 and other to FID 1. But I need do this for more than 200.000 features in some cases the field CPFS* have mor than 15 codes...

Comment: OK , so for the 8 records you show in the example image above, there are a total of 18 records that would be produced?

Comment: @smiller I suspect that FID 0 & 1 are the same feature, and that Bruno wants the FID 0 to have the first number and FID 1 to have the second. With FIDs 2 thru 4, 2 gets the first, 3 gets the second, and 4 gets the third.

Comment: Yes, if I have 3 codes in the line CPFS (xxxxx,yyyyyy,zzzzzz) I have 3 features and for each one I need for feature 1 - xxxxxxx, feature 2 - yyyyyyyy and feature 3 - zzzzzzz

Answer (score 1):

After splitting the `CPFS_CNPJS` field content into `lista`, your code loops over `lista` and overwrite the value of `row[1]` each time, effectively storing the **last** value of `lista`.

To record the 1st value of `lista`, replace the loop by `row[1] = lista[0]`

Comment: I try it, but than the only value is the first "CPFs*" in all rows

Answer (score 0):

You can to get a bit fancy with try/excepts, logic tests, and string manipulations.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature, ["CPFS_CNPJS", "identifica"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try: vals
        except NameError:
            i = 0
            vals = row [0]
            valLi = vals.split (",")
            val = valLi [0]
            row = (vals, val)
            cursor.updateRow (row)
            i += 1
            if i >= len (valLi):
                del vals
            continue
        val = valLi [i]
        row = (vals, val)
        cursor.updateRow (row)
        i += 1
        if i >= len (valLi):
            del vals
```

Example rows:

```
rows = [["1,2,3", "1"],
        ["1,2,3", "1"],
        ["1,2,3", "1"],
        ["5", "5"],
        ["7,8,9", "7"],
        ["7,8,9", "7"],
        ["7,8,9", "7"]]
```

Result:

```
('1,2,3', '1')
('1,2,3', '2')
('1,2,3', '3')
('5', '5')
('7,8,9', '7')
('7,8,9', '8')
('7,8,9', '9')
```